# UWP deployment failed with CodenameOne

Tags: codenameone

I'am trying to deploy an UWP application generated with CodenameOne.
I'am using Eclipse Mars.2 and Java 8 update 101. My Windows 10 desktop version is 1607 (last build 14393.105).
I have downloaded the package from CodenameOne Dashboard and extract it on a folder. I have also copied the "dependencies" folder in the correspondind folder.
Then I launch "Add-AppDevPackage.ps1" in PowerShell and the following error raises (in french sorry):
"Windows ne peut pas installer le package XXXXX.com.codename1.db, car le package Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug a été
fourni mais pas utilisé. Cela peut être dû au fait que le package XXXXX.com.codename1.db ne dépend pas de
Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug. Seuls les packages dont dépend le package XXXXX.com.codename1.db peuvent être installés."

Have you an idea about this issue. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, the dependencies that are listed in the developer guide were out of date.  I have updated them on Github [here](https://github.com/codenameone/cn1-binaries/tree/master/uwp/Dependencies)  The only difference is that it uses the Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.appx library instead of Microsoft.VCLibs.140.00.Debug.appx.

If you use these dependencies instead, it should fix your error.